# composite primary key (2 columns) with foreign key constraint to 2 tables, adding further constraints

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to model the following SQLAlchemy models.

```
Block -> (pk-block_id, ...)
Floor -> (pk-floor_id, fk-block_id, ...)
Number -> (pk-number_id, fk-block_id, ...)
Unit -> (pk-fk-floor_id, pk-fk-number_id, ...)
```

Unit has a composite primary key that is made up of `(floor_id, number_id)` foreign keys.

I want to further constraint the foreign keys of `Unit` to `Unit.floor.block_id == Unit.number.block_id`.

How could I model something like that? The following is the pseudo code.

```
class Block(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Floor(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    block_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('blocks.id'))

class Number(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    block_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('blocks.id'))

class Unit(Base):
    floor_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [floor_id, number_id],
            ['floors.id', 'numbers.id']
            ),
        )
    # FIXME: Want to constraints Unit.floor.block_id == Unit.number.block_id
```

Thanks!